# Remove padding between div in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap 3. I want to divide a row into 8-column and 4-column, also add the background for the row

```
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="abc" style="background:blue">a</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="abc" style="background:blue; border:1px solid red">b</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

but I dont know why there is a blank space between two column. So, how can I remove the blank. Below is a image for more detail.[image: Your picture]

ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: `style='padding: 0px;'`

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### View Live <kbd>**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Z43tijep1J)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}

.row.no-gutter {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-lg-8"><div>one</div></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"><div>two</div></div>
</div>
```

#### Snap

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this

HTML

```
<div class="row" >
                <div class="col-sm-8 paddin0 margin0">
                    <div class="abc" style="background:blue">a</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 paddin0 margin0">
                    <div class="abc" style="background:blue; border:1px solid red">b</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.paddin0 {
padding:0px !important
}
.margin0{
margin:0px; !important
}
```

Comment: that sole the blank problem, but two column is overflow outside
http://s13.postimg.org/pqny7ls47/abc.png

Answer (score 0):

I´m not bootstrap guru, what about adding blue background to parent `.row` instead of two children divs?

```
<div class="row" style="background:blue">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="abc">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="abc" border:1px solid red">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css file

```
.nopadding {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

also, add that class to your column div's

having a new html code:

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-8 nopadding">
        <div class="abc" style="background:blue">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 nopadding">
        <div class="abc" style="background:blue; border:1px solid red">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

that will remove the padding.

**Why I added a new css class?**

Because you might need the default css structure of the boostrap, keeping them is a good idea and also the `nopadding` class can be used also to other div that you want to removed their padding.

Hope it helps.

Comment: remove the row, that will make it.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use minus margin on that red lined div like margin-left:-30px , see demo here :

http://www.bootply.com/DDhnkOqeID

Cheers !